# is it ok to work with ts dev branch compiler in vs 2012

Tags: typescript

recently i reported problems working with ts inside of visual studio... https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/1803... we basically have to restart vs every five minutes, literally... as you can imagine working like this is frustrating to say the least... we understand that the next release of ts should resolve these issues but the people around here are getting really frustrated and impatient... so we're trying to see if working with the current dev branch of the ts compiler will resolve our issues... we understand that working with the dev branch is risky... but at this point things are so bad with the 0.9.1.1 version that we're thinking working with the dev branch is the lesser evil for now... and besides ts isn't even oficially released to begin with... anyway, so we've downloaded and compiled the dev branch version of the ts compiler and replaced the 0.9.1.1 files with the dev versions... we can tell these new files are being picked up because now we have a ton of errors when compiling our solution which we did not have before...

anyway, i guess my question is, is working with the dev branch of the ts compiler inside of vs ok? i don't understand the internals of all of this, but from what i can tell there are two components at play, the vs plug in and the ts compiler... i believe the ts dev branch only provides the ts compiler, not the vs plug in... for example, when compiling the dev  branch, i noticed that the output did not include an updated tsc.exe file... can anyone tell me whether or not it should be ok to use the dev branch ts compiler inside of vs???? or is it necessary to have an updated vs ts plugin????

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing this is [somewhat officially supported](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2013/01/29/trying-the-latest-typescript-build.aspx).

Your guess about the structure of the VS plug-in and the compiler is correct. The open source component (which builds to JS) is built from the git repository, and there's a separate non-open-source component that hosts this file inside VS and marshals between the managed side and the JavaScript side.

Whether it's safe to take a JS build from the develop branch and drop it in with the managed side is dependent on whether there have been any breaking changes on that interface the plugin uses to talk to the TypeScript language service. The team doesn't explicitly track when those breaking changes occur (sometimes they are subtle and it isn't even realized that it happened), so you're basically on your own. I can tell you that the develop branch is significantly more stable than 0.9.1.1, so even if there are some breaking changes that cause some problems, you might be better off.

TL;DR: It's fine to try, and it may very well work better, but it also might not work at all.